# Drawing text in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, drawrect

I used the following method to draw text in my custome cell, it's working fine but I just found that part of the text missing(Not showing all text in the cell):

```
- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)rect {

    UIColor * textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if (self.selected || self.highlighted){
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
        UIRectFill(self.bounds);
    }

    [textColor set];

    UIFont * textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:rect.size];



    [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-(textSize.width+2  ) ,
                                (rect.size.height / 2) - (textSize.height / 2),
                                textSize.width, textSize.height) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];


}
```

Thanks, please advice.

Comment: Why aren't you using a UILabel for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the space for drawing bigger than the `textSize.width, textSize.heigh`

```
UIFont * textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

CGSize sizeMe = CGSizeMake(300, rect.size.height*1.5);
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:sizeMe];
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-(textSize.width+10 ) ,
(rect.size.height / 2) - (textSize.height / 2),
textSize.width, textSize.height+(textSize.height*1.5)) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change the line that determines text size to:

```
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:rect.size lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not consider the lineBreakMode in sizeWithFont. You may want to use `– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` instead for determine the actual size.

BTW, when your constraint is exactly the rect.size then the return value will never be larger than the actual rect.size. That may be what you want. Whenever I deal with strings of variable length in custom cells, I like to know whether the string fits in or not and may enlarge the individual cell (which requieres some more work of course). 
If you do that then set the `size.height` of the constraints size to something very high. `10000.0f` or so.

Comment: I tied and Not Working.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a custom cell .What is the need for drawing the text into it?That is the purpose of Label just add as the subview and use it.

drawInRect is a coregraphics drawing method

as per docs

> Draws the string in the current graphics context using the specified
>   bounding rectangle and font. This method draws as much of the string
>   as possible using the given font and constraints. This method uses the
>   UILineBreakModeWordWrap line break mode and the UITextAlignmentLeft
>   alignment.

I dont see you get the context before drawing .Hence it doesnot have a valid context.and hence not drawing